# Prevent Twitter Bootstrap .span2 from resizing in responsive layout

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to prevent a `.span2` from resizing, while keeping a responsive layout.

My code looks like this

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row-fluid">

<!-- Toolbar -->
<section id="toolbar" class="span2">
   Toolbar
</section>

<!-- Code input -->
   Code input
</section>

<!-- Code preview -->
<section class="span5">
   Code preview
</section>

</div><!-- /.row-fluid -->
</div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
```

Basically what I want is while resizing other elements(`.span5`) I want for `#toobar` to have a fixed widht. Is that possible?

Comment: What do you mean by `while keeping a responsive layout`? Is it "when it is in a smaller viewport' ?

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just assign a fixed width to `#toolbar`?

```
#toolbar {
  width: 200px;
}
```

Comment: I think he means assign it in a custom responsive stylesheet that would load after the twitter bootstrap one. You could also override the .span2 width in a custom responsive stylesheet that is inserted after twitters. Make sure you use your the right media query so it doesn't appear on bigger resolutions, giving you your big white space

Comment: @intelis - It's impossible to determine the exact width values or changes you'll need.  If you want help specific to your code, you need to provide a working example.  My solution is extremely simple, as was your request.  You wanted `#toolbar` set at a fixed width, this is how you do it.  Since `#toolbar` is an ID, it will have definition priority over the css class definitions for `.span2`